# Why website copy tools like Cyotek WebCopy and HTTrack cannot find files that search engines like Google can?

Tags: google-search, web-crawlers, search-engines, download, copy

I would like to keep the target website private, but here are some details:

- It's a personal (as in single-author) public documentation / portfolio / blog sort of website
- It seems to be hosted using Apache
- The contents are static as far as I can tell
- When using browser on some relative paths it serves them using the browser's 'Index of' view of files
- It does not seem to have robot.txt
- It has a root index.html
- This is not some "secret" information (it's in public web and there are no logins/accounts there)
- There are "public" images and html files there that are not (ultimately) linked from index.html . The subj tools Cyotek WebCopy and HTTrack cannot find those files, yet Google can: site:example.com etc.

What does Google do that those web copy tools don't?

The idea of this exercise is to both preserve a copy and discover things not yet linked. I am asking this question to ideally both:

Find a way to copy the full website as seen by search engines.
Understand a bit more about the web.

Comment: Questions here are required to be [about operating and managing your own website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There's really no way for us to know how these different tools operate, or what the differences might be, but [Googlebot](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/googlebot) doesn't copy files, it just indexes and stores part of them as database _cache_ so it can compare updates.

Comment: How it does that is not fully disclosed to the public, other than they use the [Chromium rendering engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googlebot). Perhaps other tools do not fully render pages like the Googlebot does (note it's very difficult to tell whether a page is dynamic or static since that can occur on the server-side). Discussing how to crawl and copy sites would really be too [broadly scoped](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for this site as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a specific URL the web-copy-tools like HTTrack will only *crawl* the HTML response and only resources that are ultimately crawlable from that initial HTML response are accessible (not just resources that are directly linked from that initial URL).

Whereas Google also:

- can process (XML) sitemaps that might have been submitted by the website author in Google Search Console (GSC). These can contain standard page URLs, images and other resources. These might otherwise be "hidden" from crawlers. (They can be made "public"/linked to with the `Sitemap:` directive in `robots.txt` - but if there's no `robots.txt` file...)
- is able to discover pages/resources that have been linked to by external websites. This might include "old" URLs/resources that were once part of the site but the link on the site itself has been removed, but the content still remains.
- is able to parse JavaScript and discover URLs in JS generated content.